# it's possible pass by reference a method from a class to a global function or between classes?

Tags: c++, c++14, pass-by-reference

I was wondering if it's possible pass by reference a method from a class to a global function?

consider this, Example:

```
void FuncSet(int* x)
{
    *x = 4;
}

void (&RefSet)(int*) = FuncSet; // reference to FuncSet();
```

Now then, i've tried something like:

```
class x
{
    public:
        int SetSome(int* x)
        {
             *x = 4;
        }
};
int(&DeclRef)(int*) = x::SetSome;
```

I've obtained something like:

> ```
>  [Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int
>  (&)(int*)' from an rvalue of type 'int (x::*)(int*)'
> ```

Or classes by classes:

```
class x
{
    public:
        int SetSome(int * x)
        {
            *x = 4; 
        }
};


class y
{
    public:
        int (&RefSet)(int*); // i can't do something like this: int(y::&RefSet)(int*);
};
int(y::RefSet)(int*) = x::SetSome; // same.
```

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: use std::function<> instead of reference-to-function.

Comment: What is your end goal here?  `std::function` and lambdas would be a good place to start.

Comment: I knew about the use of `std::function`, just wanted to know If it was possible something like what i've publish, i've searched everywhere and i've not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can have member pointer:

```
int (X::*DeclRef)(int*) = &x::SetSome;
```

with usage

```
X x;
int i;
(x.*DeclRef)(&i);
```